# permutatitons of elements in array using fork in c

Tags: c, arrays, fork, permutation

```
int dp[2];                                                                           
void sortOutput() {                                                                  
    pipe(dp); pid_t p = fork();                                                      
    if(p == 0) { close(STDOUT_FILENO); close(dp[0]); dup2(dp[1], STDOUT_FILENO); }   
    else { close(STDIN_FILENO); close(dp[1]); dup2(dp[0], STDIN_FILENO);             
        char str[256][256]; int lines = 0;                                           
        while(!feof(stdin) && lines < 256) { fgets(str[lines],256,stdin);    lines++; }
        qsort(str,lines,256,(void*)strcmp);                                          
        for(;lines>0;lines--) fputs(str[lines],stdout);                              
        int s; waitpid(p,&s,0); exit(0);                                             
    }                                                                                
}               


    int arr[4];

    void swap(int i, int j) {
        int t = arr[j];
        arr[j] = arr[i];
        arr[i] = t;
    }

    int main() {
        int n, i;

        for(i = 0; i < 4; i++)
            scanf("%d",&arr[i]);
        printf("\n");
        sortOutput();   

        pid_t p;
        int s;
        //BELOW IS WHERE I AM HAVING TROUBLE,CODE BELOW I SUCCESFULLY CREATED 24 PROCESSES
        p = fork();


        p = fork();
        if(p == 0) swap(2,3);
        else waitpid(p,&s,0);

        p = fork();
        if(p == 0) swap(0,1);
        else waitpid(p,&s,0);

        p = fork();
        if(p == 0) {
           swap(1,3);

           p = fork();
           if(p == 0) swap(0,3);
           else waitpid(p,&s,0);
        }else waitpid(p,&s,0);

        p = fork();
        if(p == 0) swap(3,2);
        else waitpid(p,&s,0);
        //UP UNTIL HERE 








        for(i = 0; i < 4; i++)
            printf("%d ", arr[i]);
        printf("\n");

        exit(0);
        return 0;
    }
```

hello everyone,i was trying to find all permutations of elements in an array using forks in c.To do that,i needed to create 24 processes to succesfully calculate all the possibilities of 4 elements.I waas managed to create 24 processes but couldnt seem to figure out how the swap indexes should be to perform 24 unique permutations.I draw all the process map on a paper and tried so many things on that,but unfortunately i couldnt come up with a solution.So if anyone could point me into right direction as to how one could go around something like this,it would be appreciated. thanks in advance

Comment: What output are you currently getting and what output would you like to get?

Comment: what i want to get is lets say using number of 1,2,3,4 ,i want to get all possible unique permutations of this 4 numbers like (1,2,3,4     1,2,4,3          1,3,2,4      1,3,4,2 and so on for each element). What i am getting is ununique outputs,not all of them but almost half of them are ununique)

Comment: maybe try doing it without `fork` first and then when you've got the logic working, see if you can do it with multiple processes?